Conceptual links between exponential decay and the normal distribution?
The standard normal distribution is given by
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}
$$
and exponential decay is given by
$$
N(t) = N_0 e^{-\lambda t}
$$
These formulae are equivalent if we consider $N_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, $t = x$, and $\lambda (t) = \frac{1}{2} x$. Thus, the probability density of the standard normal can be seen as an exponential decay of the "initial" probability density $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, where the rate of decay $\lambda$ increases proportionally with "time" (distance from the mean).
My question is this: are there any insights or deeper conceptual connections to be drawn from observing this relationship? I have a vague sense that there might be some connection between the memorylessness property of self-proportional decay and the maximum entropy property of the normal distribution, in the sense that memorylessness gives minimal information (maximal entropy) about the history of a time-varying process. Or more generally, that some properties of the normal distribution can be understood in terms of some properties of exponential growth/decay, or vice versa. I'd love to have a deeper understanding of whatever connections there might be here.

I think the substitution $t\to x^2$ is inconsistent with the definition of exponential decay.

I don’t think there is much to compare here since one is bounded under and the other is unbounded. Exponential decay is linked with geometric law and normal distribution with binomial law which are very different

One correspondence between the two is that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal random variables, then $X^2 + Y^2$ has the PDF $f(x) = \frac12 e^{-x/2}$ for $x\ge 0$, and so it has the exponential distribution with rate $\lambda = \frac12$.
